# Password Protection vs AES Encryption

Tags: encryption

I have gotten very curious about how data is secured from hackers and I was wondering about the difference between password protecting an excel file vs encrypting it with AES. I have found that both methods encrypt the files, and also require the user to type in a password to decrypt them. So why is password protecting easier to break?

Thanks

Comment: They are not distinct methods. Password protection can be achieved by deriving an AES key from a password and then encrypting the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For simplicity I'll demonstrate with only lowercase english letters)

When using a password you have 26 letters `a-z`.
With AES-128 the key is `128/8 = 16` letters.
So the possible number of combinations with only lowercase english letters are `26^16 = 43608742899428874059776`.

If you on the otherhand use ALL possible values for the key that would be `256^16 = 3.4028236692093846346337460743177e+38` number of combinations. (That is more than 7803076000000000 times more combinations which would result in that much more time to "crack").

As you can see there are a lot more possible keys with a randomly generated AES key than with using a password.

This is a gross simplification, not concidering salt, key expansion, etc, but should get the point through.

Comment: All of that is rendered more or less solved with a decent KDF however.